# Почему деструктор вызывается 2 раза и вызывает ошибку памяти?

Tags: c++, классы

Файл с реализацией

```
#include "Matrices.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
Matrix::Matrix()
{
    rows = 1;
    cols = 1;
    allocSpace();
    data[0][0] = 0;
}
Matrix::Matrix(double** _data, int _rows, int _cols)
{
    rows = _rows;
    cols = _cols;
    allocSpace();
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
        {
            data[i][j] = _data[i][j];
        }
    }
}
Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    cout << "destructor" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        delete[] data[i];
    }
    delete[] data;
}
void Matrix::allocSpace()
{
    data = new double*[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {

        data[i] = new double[cols];
    }
}
ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, Matrix matrix)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.cols; ++j)
        {
            out << matrix.data[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        out << endl;
    }
    return out;
}
```

Файл с объявлением

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Matrix
{
private:
    double** data;
    int rows;
    int cols;
public:
    Matrix();
    Matrix(double** _data,int _rows, int _cols);
    ~Matrix();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Matrix matrix);
    //friend Matrix operator;
    void allocSpace();



};
```

Source

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Matrices.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    double** kek = new double*[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        kek[i] = new double[3];
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            kek[i][j] = i;
        }
    }
    Matrix kek1(kek, 4, 3);
    cout << kek1 << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

При запуске Source видно,что деструктор срабатывает дважды и залазит в чужую память,как с этим бороться и почему-то деструктор сработал дважды?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оператор вывода `friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Matrix matrix);` принимает на вход экземпляр класса `Matrix` по значению. Соответственно вызов этого оператора создает временный объект. Исправьте оператор, чтобы он принимал константную ссылку, реализуйте или запретите конструкторы и операторы копирования / перемещений.

Comment: Спасибо огромное,сидел больше часа,залипая в код

Comment: @YoungStudent Стоило использовать отладчик, поставить точку останова в деструктор и поглядеть, откуда он вызывается.